# Problem uploading different files as custom fields with front end post form

Tags: custom-field, uploads, forms, front-end

I have a front end post form that I'm having some problems getting the right path for the media to save as custom fields. The path to the file gets saved as mysite.com/home/betauser/public_html/betatheme/wp_content/....file path. How do I get the path to save correctly?

```
<?php if( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_post") {
if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' )) { 
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');
}
$file=$_FILES;
// Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content
if (isset ($_POST['title'])) {
    $title =  $_POST['title'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter a game  title';
}
if (isset ($_POST['description'])) {
    $description = $_POST['description'];
} else {
    echo 'Please enter the content';
}
$tags = $_POST['post_tags'];

// Add the content of the form to $post as an array
$new_post = array(
    'post_title'    => $title,
    'post_content'  => $description,
    'post_category' => 11,
    'tags_input'    => array($tags),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',           // Choose: publish, preview, future, draft, etc.
    'post_type' => fod_music  // Use a custom post type if you want to
);
$overrides = array( 'test_form' => false);
$uploaded_music = wp_handle_upload( $file['music_file'], $overrides );
$uploaded_music_art = wp_handle_upload( $file['music_image'], $overrides ); 
//save the new post and return its ID
$pid = wp_insert_post($new_post);
update_post_meta($pid,'music_code',$uploaded_music['file']);
update_post_meta($pid,'music_art',$uploaded_music_art['file']);
wp_redirect( get_permalink($pid)); 
exit();

} 
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');
?>

<div id="postbox">
 <form id="new_post" name="new_post" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p><label for="title">Song Title</label><br />
   <input type="text" id="title" value="" tabindex="1" size="20" name="title" />
  </p>
  <p><label for="music_file">Upload a song</label><br />
   <input type="file" name="music_file" id="music_file"/>
  </p>
  <p><label for="description">Description</label><br />
   <textarea id="description" tabindex="3" name="description" cols="50" rows="6"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p><label for="music_image">Upload a music art</label><br />
   <input type="file" name="music_image" id="music_image"/>
  </p>
  <p><label for="post_tags">Tags</label>
   <input type="text" value="" tabindex="5" size="16" name="post_tags" id="post_tags" /></p>
  <p align="right"><input type="submit" value="Publish" tabindex="6" id="submit" name="submit" /></p>
  <input type="hidden" name="action" value="new_post" />
  <?php wp_nonce_field( 'new-post' ); ?>
 </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the 'post_category' argument only accepts category ID's, so you will have to find that through your database, or through get_category_by_slug:

```
$cat = get_category_by_slug( 'music' ); 
$cat_id = $cat->term_id;
```

Secondly, look at your wp_handle_upload() section. You are passing $file['file'] in both cases, where 'file' is not the name of either of your upload fields. I believe it should be:

```
$uploaded_music = wp_handle_upload( $file['music_file'], $overrides );
$uploaded_music_art = wp_handle_upload( $file['music_image'], $overrides );
```

Comment: yeap I had just caught both those things. Do you know why it's storing the wrong paths to the media?

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the issue with the path saved and upvoted this answer.

Comment: What are the paths being given?

Comment: You can see the path example in the edited question. It's adding path from my server to the path.

Comment: instead of 'file' from the returned values, use 'url'. See the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload#Return_values) for why.

`update_post_meta($pid,'music_code',$uploaded_music['url']);
update_post_meta($pid,'music_art',$uploaded_music_art['url']);`

Comment: yeap thx a lot!